# Error installing pythonmagick , ImportError: No module named PythonMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I am trying to install pythonmagick on OSX (High Sierra).

I followed DwishR's instructions here: https://gist.github.com/tomekwojcik/2778301
Downloaded pythonmagick from here: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/
Modified BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0/
and the make files.

See my install procedure here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2eab85b89fd7be33efa40bf3cb1015e

However, you can see that pythonmagick is not working at the end. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check which python is used. It looks like you are using the system python which is not using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. You might want to install python2 with brew: `brew install python@2`.

Comment: This was it, I needed set my path to the brew python.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a rather old package, missing what it needs to be installed with pip.

Take a look at this issue:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4629#issuecomment-317844966

I quote:

> PythonMagick is on PyPi, but there are no source distribution, eggs, or wheels provided, so it can't be installed. PythonMagickWand as an egg, but only for Python 2.5!

I see you are using OSX High Sierra, so your current version of Python 2 is 2.7. You could try building a virtualenv using `pyenv` and python 2.5, but maybe [pgmagick](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/) would be a suitable replacement?

Comment: I think the Pip through your answer off. Please see dishr's instructions.  PythonMagick needs Python >2.2 I believe. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonMagick/0.5. What am I missing?  I need to use PythonMagick, no replacement. As I have code already written to use it.